# Firefox deletes persistent Cookies

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, cookies, persistent

I've been trying to get a `html/js` based Language selection system to work and I need a persistent cookie for it, which saves the choice of Language the user made, for a certain amount of time.

Sadly this cookie is mistaken by Firefox for an activity tracking cookie(which it kinda is), and thus is deleted, when the session ends.

Can I prevent this from happening somehow?

If this script would work, my finished code should work aswell:

```
if(document.cookie.indexOf("test=") < 0){
            document.cookie = "test=Hello World; max-age=3600";
        }
else{
            window.location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/");
        }
```

What it should do:

1. The first time the site is opened, a cookie is set and nothing further happens.
2. The second time the user gets redirected to youtube.com.

What it does:

1. The first time the site is opened, a cookie is set and nothing further happens.
2. If the Site is then refreshed or opened in another tab, the user gets redirected to youtube.com. If the browser or tab is closed however, the cookie will be lost and we're back at step 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, i'm no javascript expert. But i noticed that the most documentation recommend to check if cookie exist are suggesting to do it like this: `document.cookie.indexOf("test=")` so perhaps the cookie isn't deleted but your check if cookie exist using the wrong method.

```
if(document.cookie.indexOf("test=") < 0){
        document.cookie = "test=Hello World; max-age=3600";
}
else{
        window.location.replace("https://www.youtube.com/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arjan, I tried out the .indexOf method, but the result stays the same. I've edited the original post and added a bit more information.

Comment: I'm on linux, and just tested it with firefox. Here it works as it should. So i can't reproduce your problem.